# Yii2 - onClick event on Nav Widget

Tags: javascript, yii2, onclick

I have this navBar:

```
<?= Nav::widget([
    'items'  => [
        [
            'label'   => ...
            'url'     => ...
            'active'  => ...
            'linkOptions' => array('onclick'=>'setButtonValue("stringValue")'),
        ],
```

When I click this Nav option I want to set the value of a button of the same page with "stringValue"

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="buttonQuestion" value="">
    <i class="fas fa-question"></i>
</button>
```

At the end of the page I'm registering the function:

```
$this->registerJs(
    "function setButtonValue(stringValue) { alert('Button clicked!'); });",
);
?>
```

But In the console I got the following error;

> setButtonValue is not defined

Am I using a wrong approach ?

Comment: is there any special reason for using `onclick` attribute and not using event delegation `$( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {` i would suggest assigning `id` to those links you want to bind click and use event delegation if the links need to call different functions , and if they need a single method to call then you can use `class`

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong ) in your js   code

remove the `)` after closing `}`

```
function setButtonValue(stringValue) { alert('Button clicked!'); });,  
                                                                  ^^ here
```

.

```
$this->registerJs(
  "function setButtonValue(stringValue) { alert('Button clicked!'); };",
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way too:

**NavBar**

```
...
'linkOptions' => array('onclick'=>'$(this).html("stringValue");'),
...
```

Here is the Example

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li onclick="$(this).html('Changed');">Text</li>
```